# Is there a utility in the Android SDK or in Java to replace parts of a string using placeholders?

Tags: java, android, string, replace

It would work something like this

```
someUtility.replace ("Hello, my name is {1}.  What is your {2}?", "Mark", "name");
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
String.format("Hello, my name is %1$s.  What is your %2$s?", "Mark", "name");
```

or if you will just use each once in order:

```
String.format("Hello, my name is %s.  What is your %s?", "Mark", "name");
```

Comment: as far as I know,printf does that too!

Comment: I do it like this: String.format("Hello, my name is %s.  What is your %s?", "Mark", "name");

Answer (score 2):

Look at [MessageFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)):

```
MessageFormat.format("Hello, my name is {0}.  What is your {1}?", "Mark", "name");
```

Usually I prefer `String.format` or `System.out.printf` though for c-style formatting (sort of), as Matthew suggested.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use Spring the Resource Bundles will give you the actual exact style of replacement that you have displayed. You can see some examples here: http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-resource-bundle-with-resourcebundlemessagesource-example/

Comment: Android doesn't use Resource Bundles.  The API for doing this with Android's resource system is: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getString(int, java.lang.Object...)